# Iceweasel chooses random font

Tags: fonts, iceweasel

My Iceweasel browser was working fine until yesterday when I installed some new fonts in my system after which webpages are displayed in some random font. This does not happen on all websites but on those websites where the default fonts are loaded. Here's a screenshot:

[image]
I think this is happening due to some other fallback font. But iceweasel's default font is DejaVu Sans. I tried to delete the font being used, but then it chooses some next random font.

I am new to linux. Can anyone help me with this.

---

**Edit**

Distro Version:

```
abhishek@ab-linux:~$ uname -a
Linux ab-linux 3.7-trunk-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.7.2-0+kali8 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Desktop Manager is : `GNOME 3.4.2`

Comment: Rather than deleting the font, try reinstalling DejaVu Sans, and resetting Iceweasel.

Answer (score 0):

Please let us know your distro version and Desktop manager (KDE, Gnome etc), but generally speaking and assuming you use a debian-ubuntu based distro I would check reinstall default fonts packages and would reconfig them following these commands

```
  $ dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig-config
  $ dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig
```

https://wiki.debian.org/Fonts

Comment: I've updated the info and reconfigured the fonts, but nothing happened. I've currently managed my browser to use some stable readable font by delete and trial.

Comment: this tool would help you figure out which one is missing. http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/install-manage-fonts-under-gnome.html sorry but I am on KDE, not sure about Gnome fonts.

Comment: Gnome Font Manager is already installed And the default font `Deja Vu Sans` is not missing but rather than using this as fallback font it uses some random font present in system

Comment: what about doing `dpkg-reconfigure iceweasel` or creating a different iceweasel profile? You can try to launch it with other user like `sudo iceweasel` . If doing login with other user the bug dissappears I suggest you simply reset your iceweasel profile with `rm -fr ~/.mozilla/firefox/<<profile-name>` Not sure if the path is correct though